# How to get all of the matching pandas Dataframe rows in which a grouping in one column includes a match in another column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, match, conditional-statements

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...      {'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz'],
...      'B': ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'grey', 'red']})
>>> df
     A       B
0  foo     red
1  foo    blue
2  bar  yellow
3  bar   green
4  baz    grey
5  baz     red
```

I want to filter for all of the rows in which an element in column `A` has a value of 'red' in column `B`. If I do a simple filter I get:

```
>>> df[df['B'] == 'red']
     A    B
0  foo  red
5  baz  red
```

But I want **all** of the rows for foo and baz since **any** of those rows have 'red' in column `B`:

```
     A       B
0  foo     red
1  foo    blue
4  baz    grey
5  baz     red
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find all [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of `A` where condition:

```
print (df.ix[df['B'] == 'red', 'A'].unique())
['foo' 'baz']
```

Then use another condition with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.A.isin(df.ix[df['B'] == 'red', 'A'].unique()))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: A, dtype: bool

print (df[df.A.isin(df.ix[df['B'] == 'red', 'A'].unique())])
     A     B
0  foo   red
1  foo  blue
4  baz  grey
5  baz   red
```

In sample can be omit `unique`, if there is only one `red` value per group. But if there is multiple values, `unique` is necessary.